# node_modules весит 200 мб,что я делаю не так?

Tags: reactjs

В созданном приложение на react  папка  node_modules весит 200 мб, как ее конвертировать или может я какую то команду не прописал чтобы оно все сжалось?

Comment: Все нормально, node_modules `react-create-app` из коробки примерно столько вести

Comment: Это абсолютно нормально https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Euib.jpg

Comment: Так, а в чем суть вопроса? `node_modules` часто превышает 200 мб...

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо немного поразмыслить над депенденсами, поэтому в качестве средства я могу порекомендовать [`yarn`](https://yarnpkg.com/uk/). Со следующей команды начинается новый проект

```
yarn init
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё нормально, просто не надо её в репозиторий коммитить.